# Whats a better way to add conditional input to views in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a preview view of a page that I'm building up with a step by step form. Currently the preview view doesn't work, all it has is a default page with default text and styling. My task is to get the preview to display as a user submits the elements of the page through the form. This is what the default view would look like:

```
<h1>
  Worlds coolest Product
</h1>

<h3>
Buy me and make your life 10x more worthwhile! :)
</h3>
```

and this default text is rendered out by a partial that looks like this:

```
<%= render 'manage/deal_steps/deal/main_header' %>
```

...

My problem  is that I need to replace the default text with the user submitted text if there is any but I also need to keep the default text just in case the user doesn't submit any thing. This way I will not get any errors if there is no 
input. Keeping it simple, Is there any way to achieve this effect without littering the view with conditional logic like this:

```
<h1>
  <%if retrieve_content('header')!= nil %>
  <%= retrieve_content('header')%>
  <%else%>
  Worlds coolest Product
  <% end%>
</h1>

<h3>
<%if retrieve_content('header_two')!= nil %>
  <%= retrieve_content('header_two')%>
<%else%>
Buy me and make your life 10x more worthwhile! :)
<%end%>
</h3>
```

Comment: Take a look into `presenters` in Rails.

Comment: Hey Igor thank you for the tip. I looked into it. It seems to be a good way to extract the logic out of the view and to make reusable view methods that I can place into the view. ::) Still no way to leave the conditional approach alone really, but It does make the view cleaner. So i will accept this answer. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you the same results as your current code:

```
<h1>
  <%= retrieve_content('header') || 'Worlds coolest Product' %>
</h1>

<h3>
  <%= retrieve_content('header_two') || 'Buy me and make your life 10x more worthwhile! :)' %>
</h3>
```

Comment: Very witty and exactly what I was looking to address the problem with. I am going to go with using presenters but this will certainly litter the presenter class undoubtably. thank you

Answer (score 2):

Modify your 'retrieve_content' method to accept second, optional  attribute defualt. It would look sth like:

```
def retrieve_content(key, default = nil)
  <Your old logic> || default
end
```

Then you can use it:

```
<h1>
  <%= retrieve_content('header', 'Worlds coolest Product') %>
</h1>
```

If your default text is much more complicated (includes html and stuff), accept an optional block and use capture helpers.